# Syntax for DNS BIND full domain ?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I created zone file

```
zone "example.com" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/db.example.com";
    forwarders{};
};
```

db.example.com

```
$TTL    604800
@ IN SOA pgdebian.example.com. contact.example.com.
(20881122 604800 86400 2419200 604800 )

                NS      pgdebian.xxx.com.
pgdebian        A       192.168.0.49        
pgdebian        HINFO   "PII 233 :-)" "Debian Testing"
*               A       127.0.0.1
```

Now, when I request http://lol.example.com, BIND9 answers 127.0.0.1
But if I try `nslookup example.com`, nslookup says SERVER FAILED.

How can I redirect example.com to 127.0.0.1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wildcard is matching children of example.com but not example.com proper.

Add this record:

```
@ A 127.0.0.1
```

to add 127.0.0.1 as an address for example.com itself.

[The Wikipedia article on wildcard DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record) is pretty good.